# Search file in ALL SD Card

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to search a file in ALL the SD Card with ".apk" extension. I've written this method.

```
public void scan(File file) {
    mFile = file.listFiles();

    if(mFile != null) {
        for(int i=0;i<mFile.length;i++) {
            if(mFile[i] != null) {
                if(mFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    scan(mFile[i]);
                } else {
                    if(mFile[i].getName().endsWith(".apk")) {
                        lista.add(mFile[i].getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

And I passed as parameter

```
scan(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

The problem is that also if I've some apk files into SD Card the array list size is 0 and no one apk files is detected by this method. Why? My goal is to scan ALL the sd card to search .apk files.

Comment: Most users will not have .apk files in that location. Are you shure there are in your case?

Comment: My apk files are in /Download folder.

Comment: Please give full path.

Comment: `mFile = file.listFiles();`. After that statement check if mFile is null and return if so. `if(mFile[i] != null)`. That will never be null. So you can remove it. Please adapt your code here. You have no exceptions mentioned in the logcat?

Comment: Already tried and is never null.

Comment: Please adapt your code here before we continue. Or post the adapted scan function in another code block.

Comment: scan method updated...

Comment: Why is `mFile` a field?

Comment: Please remove that other check for null as it is not needed. And tell the full path i asked for. Make `mFile` a local variable of scan. Please adapt the code here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `mFile` is a field, each call to `scan` does not get its own "copy" of `mFile`.

What happens when you call scan("/sdcard") is this: (I'm pretending the parameter is filename instead of a `File`, just to simplify this explanation)

1. scan("/sdcard") is entered
2. scan("/sdcard") sets mFile to the list of files in /sdcard. Say {"/sdcard/folder1", "/sdcard/folder2"}.
3. scan("/sdcard") calls scan("/sdcard/folder1") since that is the first element in mFile.
4. scan("/sdcard/folder1") sets mFile to the list of files in /sdcard/folder1. Say there are none.
5. scan("/sdcard/folder1") returns, since mFile.length is 0, k is 0, and 0<0 is not true.
6. scan("/sdcard") returns, since mFile.length is 0, k is 1, and 1<0 is not true.

Notice how it never got to /sdcard/folder2.

To fix your code, all you should need to do is make `mFile` a local variable inside `scan`.

Comment: Then you probably did not see that i gave the solution minutes before?

Answer (score 1):

Make `mFile` a local variable of scan. This is needed for recursion to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for this line in your code:

```
if(mFile[i] != null) {
```

Try this:

```
public void scan(File file) {
mFile = file.listFiles();

if(mFile != null) {
    for(int i=0;i<mFile.length;i++) {
            if(mFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                scan(mFile[i]);
            } else {
                if(mFile[i].getName().endsWith(".apk")) {
                    lista.add(mFile[i].getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first Pass dir as "/download" exact location where ur files are stored in.
 and then pass whole SD card root path
like searchAPK(new File("/download"));

and code try

```
private void searchAPK(File dir){
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        Log.i("DIR", "Found " + files.length + " in " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
        for (File file : files) {
            if(file.isFile() && isAPK(file)){
                list.add(file);
                Log.i("APK found", file.getName());
            }else if(file.isDirectory()){
                searchAPK(file.getAbsoluteFile()); 
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isAPK(File file){
        boolean is = false;
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".apk") || file.getName().endsWith(".APK")){
            is = true;
        }
        return is;
    }
```

File[] files = dir.listFiles();

file should be local array in your case